# Is there a way to create multiple directories at once with mkdir?

Tags: command-line, directory, coreutils, mkdir

If I wanted to create multiple directories (on the same level) and then feed it a comma seperated list of directory names (or something to that effect)?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

#### Short answer

`mkdir` takes multiple arguments, simply run

```
mkdir dir_1 dir_2
```

Answer (score 230):

You can use lists to create directories and it can get pretty wild.

Some examples to get people thinking about it:

```
mkdir sa{1..50}
mkdir -p sa{1..50}/sax{1..50}
mkdir {a-z}12345 
mkdir {1,2,3}
mkdir test{01..10}
mkdir -p `date '+%y%m%d'`/{1,2,3} 
mkdir -p $USER/{1,2,3}
```

1. 50 directories from sa1 through sa50
2. same but each of the directories will hold 50 times sax1 through sax50 (-p will create parent directories if they do not exist.
3. 26 directories from a12345 through z12345
4. comma separated list makes dirs 1, 2 and 3.
5. 10 directories from `test01` through `test10`.
6. same as 4 but with the current date as a directory and 1,2,3 in it.
7. same as 4 but with the current user as a directory and 1,2,3 in it.

So, if I understood it correctly and you want to create some directories, and within them new directories, then you could do this:

```
mkdir -p sa{1..10}/{1,2,3}
```

and get sa1, sa2,...,sa10 and within each dirs 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I agree with @gniourf_gniourf… there are no usages of regular expressions in your answer.  Did you mean to say something else, or to provide a different example?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf done :)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that brace expansion in not defined in the POSIX shell: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06 For example it will not work in `dash` which is the default `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu.

Comment: This answer depends on the shell doing expansion of your input before providing that input as *arguments to mkdir*. It's much more accurate to just say that mkdir can create multiple dirs with multiple arguments and *then* talk about how a given shell can make that easier.

Comment: If I try to do something like `mkdir sa$(seq 0.1 0.1 1)`, all it does is create one directory named sa0.1 and the rest 0.2, 0.3, ..., 1. How can I get decimal brace expansion without writing the entire list?

Comment: `man 1 seq` or even better `info seq`  are your friends.
This will do the job: 

`for f in $(seq -f %g 0.2 1 10) ; do mkdir -p test/$f ; done`

it will create a directory test with subdirs 0,2 up to 9,2 
Note that my local is Dutch, if LC_TYPE is en_US you will get the dot as decimal separator. The key is that `seq` accepts printf syle formatting.

Comment: I think you meant  `mkdir {a..z}12345 `  not  `mkdir {a-z}12345`

Comment: Thanks you working file .....

Comment: @Rinzwind just being curious, what is the difference between `mkdir {1,2,3}` and `mkdir 1 2 3`? practically both do the same, so when is mandatory the former?

Comment: Shoot that works as well with `touch` to create files.

Comment: @ManuelJordan ah the {1,2,3} is a simplified version. It becomes interesting when it is `mkdir {1,2,3}a{3,4}`  then you get 1a3, 1a4, 2a3, 2a4 etc.

Answer (score 68):

It's very simple, lets you want to create a directory structure such as:

```
Websites/
  static/
      cs
      js
  templates/
      html and xhtml
```

You can do it in a single command like this:

```
mkdir -p Website/{static/{cs,js},templates/html\ and\ xhtml}
```

Be careful to escape the spaces in your directory names.

Comment: You can also press tab here to expand them before running the command.

Answer (score 17):

Make a list of the names for your desired directories using line breaks instead of commas as a separator. Save that list.

```
mkdir `cat list`
```

You should now have all the directories named in your list.

Comment: Yes, that will work, however , with a caveat - the directory names have to be one whole string. If one line is `spaced dir` , then it will create two dirs , `spaced` and `dir.

Comment: Yeah - you can't even successfully do any kind of escaping for the spaces, either - `junk\ dir` in the `list` file gives two directories, `junk\ ` and `dir`.  Gave me a panic when I saw a `\ ` in a directory name.

Comment: This can be combined with the `-p` flag mentioned in other answers.  If so,  the `list` file doesn't have to include parent directories as their own lines, they will be detected and made automatically.

Comment: Make sure the 'list' file has no file ending.  list.txt will result in the creation of the directory list.txt in the location of the file. And those are backticks, not single quotes: \`cat list\` not 'cat list'.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? (thanks to muru for the `printf` tip)

```bsh
printf '%s' 'foo,bar,baz' | xargs -d, mkdir
```

```bsh
$ ls
$ printf '%s' 'foo,bar,baz' | xargs -d, mkdir
$ ls
bar  baz  foo
$
```

You can wrap it into a function for ease of use:

```bsh
function mkdir_cs {
    printf '%s' "$1" | xargs -d, mkdir
}
```

```bsh
$ ls
$ mkdir_cs 'foo,bar,baz'
$ ls
bar  baz  foo
$
```

Comment: Just a `printf "%s" "$1" | xargs -d, mkdir` should be enough.

Answer (score 7):

So you want comma separated list of directory names ? That can be done.

**Shell + coreutils**

Since everybody is posting oneliners, here's mine as well ( mkdir + parameter substitution plus + shell redirection  ).

```
DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls

DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ mkdir $( tr '[,\n]' ' '   < /home/xieerqi/dirList.txt   )                                           

DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls
dirFive/  dirfour/  dirone/  dirthree/  dirtwo/
```

**AWK**

AWK is a text processing language, but it has very nice `system()` function which will call the default shell , and run command[s] enclosed in parenthesis ( which must be a string).

```
DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ awk -F ',' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) system("mkdir "$i)}' dirList.txt                                    

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls -ld dir*                                                                                         
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi   23 Feb  9 11:41 dirList.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 Feb  9 11:42 dirone/
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 Feb  9 11:42 dirthree/
drwxrwxr-x 2 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 Feb  9 11:42 dirtwo/

DIR:/xieerqi
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat dirList.txt                                                                                     
dirone,dirtwo,dirthree
```

Or you could remove `,` with `gsub()` function, and call `system("mkdir "$0)` but that may be a problem if you want to create directories with spaces in their name

**Python**

Pythonic way of doing the same , would be to read each line, get rid of trailing `\n` , shove everything into one list, and iterate over the list items and create dirs per list item. Note that in the example bellow, `/home/xieerqi/dirList.txt` is the full path given to my file, and we make up full path of each new directory by joining string `/home/username/` and the dir name read from list. Substitute your own values as necessary

```
DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls                                                                                                  

DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ /home/xieerqi/makeDirs.py                                                                           

DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls
dirFive/  dirfour/  dirone/  dirthree/  dirtwo/

DIR:/testdir
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat /home/xieerqi/makeDirs.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
with open("/home/xieerqi/dirList.txt") as file:
   for line in file:
         for directory in line.strip().rsplit(','):
             path = '/home/xieerqi/testdir/' +  directory
             os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: I don't think the asker actually _wants_ the list to be comma-separated; I'm pretty sure that was just their guess at what the syntax might be.

Comment: Well, OP probably didn't  to exactly have comma-separated list, however it's sure may be used as a method, point being " lists can be used,too, you don't have to type out name of each dir individually". Especially that will be useful when a big list cannot be generated with ranges, like `dir{1..1000}`. Say , you want to make a directory per username, or per project, or per geographic location, like a city

Answer (score 6):

mkdir command takes multiple arguments simply run as below

```
mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3 ... dirN
```

If you would like to create multiple subdirectories then you can pass those argument in {} as shown below (use only commas to separate the argument, without spaces).

```
mkdir -p dir1 dir2/{subdir1,subdir2,subdir3,subdirN} dir3 dirN
```

Using the option "-p" to make parent directories as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the -p argument:

`mkdir -p app/code/Foo/Bar`

---

This is what the help page says about `-p`. I would not understand it by that text...

> -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed